# Triggers for multiple tables in Geopackage and DB Browser for SQLite for QGIS use

Tags: qgis, sql, geopackage, trigger, db-browser-sqlite

I need to build an automatic trigger in the database so that when inserting/updating a new polygon in the SETORES feature and filling in the CD_GEOCMU key attribute with the appropriate code, for example “3543907”, the trigger searches the MUNICIPIOS feature for the same CD_GEOCMU key column and fills in in the SETORES feature, the UF, MUNIC and SIGLA_RISC fields (automatically added). Is it possible to do this through Trigger?
Considering that the fields are of the same type.

SETORES.CD_GEOCMU = MUNICIPIOS .CD_GEOCMU
SETORES.SIGLA_RISC = MUNICIPIOS .SIGLA_RISC
SETORES.UF = MUNICIPIOS .UF
SETORES.MUNIC = MUNICIPIOS .NM_MUNICIP

I'm using the QGIS with geopackage database and DB Browser for SQLite  as DBMS to try to create this trigger.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER Setor_UF
AFTER INSERT ON Setores
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  update Setores
  set Setores.uf = Municipios.uf
  where 
  Setores.cd_geocmu = Municipios.cd_geocmu
END
```